# How can this question about Inferno be asked on this site?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

The novel [*Inferno*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Brown_novel)) written by Dan Brown isn't a science fiction or fantasy novel.

So how can anyone ask question about this novel in the *Science fiction & Fantasy site*?

[Why was the ending reversed in the movie "Inferno"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146465/why-was-the-ending-reversed-in-the-movie-inferno)

Comment: The question does have a comment questioning whether it is Science Fiction or Fantasy, and there is currently one close vote deeming it off-topic.

Comment: @Alex FYI: The current 1 VTC is mine after seeing this question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Well then it will soon  make it to review and will get closed if four others agree.

Comment: For the record, even if you don't have close-voting privileges you can still flag a question as off-topic. That will also send it to review, where it will likely get closed if it is actually off-topic.

Comment: It's a pity the question is too old to migrate.

Comment: I thought it was fantasy?

Comment: @Valorum No, it is realism. Perhaps action. The disease itself is not unrealistic enough to be in either camp. Worse things currently exist, such as smallpox.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - A synthetic plague unleashed by a doctor certainly sounds scifi-ish. I've only read the synopsis though. Also, I couldn't care less about Dan Brown's works

Comment: @Valorum No, because it depends on what sort of virus. There are man-made viruses that exist currently for research purposes through breeding and whatnot. Given that the *movie* provides literally no information on the symptoms of the disease other than that it is highly deadly and could kill a large percentage of the population, it could be nothing more than a strain of smallpox. I'm not kidding. We don't *enough* information to conclude it is unrealistic.

Comment: Note: don't confuse the book with Roger MacBride Allen's sci-fi similarly titled sci-fi novel.

Comment: @Valorum: If Tolkien had gone around telling everyone that elves and dwarves really existed... they'd have had him committed.  But regardless, that's basically Dan Brown's M.O.: Write complete nonsense and tell everyone it's true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The question is now closed

---

> How can this question about Inferno be asked on this site?

Anyone can ask any question they like on the site. The real question is why did no one flag or vote to close it as off topic when it was asked. The answer to that is probably no one thought about it too hard. The answerer has, however, commented the following:

> Plus...is this Science Fiction & Fantasy per se? "He noted after answering." :)

So someone at least guessed it might not have been SFF-nal but wasn't sure enough that they didn't VTC it.

Sometimes things stay around longer than they should because the right people aren't around at the right time.

In any case I have now cast a close vote as off topic so we shall see if it gets closed in the queue or not.

---

As has been [noted in the comments here by Alex](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12264/how-can-this-question-about-inferno-be-asked-on-this-site#comment42371_12264) you don't need to post a meta question about a question that should be closed. Until you hit 3k reputation you can always flag it as off topic to send it to queue. Once you hit 3k reputation you can then vote to close it which will also send it to queue.

Though if you're unsure you can always ask on meta as you have done here and there's usually someone hanging around in chat, in [TREU](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe), that I'm sure could help you if you just want some quick reassurance.

---

This particular question should probably have been asked on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) (it's on topic and [has already been asked there](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66566/45378)) and it may also be on topic on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) but seeing as it was asking about the movie I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: That being said, it's still not the worst idea to gather the community's perspective if you're unsure it should be closed, especially if something seems perplexing to you and you're confused enough to get insecure about the on-topicness. (Though, the meta question sounds quite...confident.)

Comment: @TARS Sure, we've had plenty of questions asking about a questions on topicness and I'm sure this won't be the last.